# vb.net: rounding to next whole number

Tags: .net, vb.net

if i have an integer a_variable = 1.1

how do i round it up to 2?

Comment: The value 1.1 cannot be stored in an integer variable. Do you mean a Single or Double variable perhaps?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Math.Ceiling(a_variable)

Comment: Math.Floor(a_variable+1) ...  : )

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean a single/double, use math.ceiling to get the next highest whole number.